# Detecting the text change jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am trying to detect if the value of the text of the div is "9" and then alert the user. But I cant get it working. Is there a way to detect the new number "9"? Thanks!

This is the live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/7gyL2h2e/5/

HTML:

```
<div id="number">8</div>
<div id="clickme">Click me +1</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#clickme").click(function(){
      $('#number').html(function(i, val) { return +val+1;});
});

if($.trim($("#number").text())=="9"){
  alert("number 9");  

}
```

Comment: You need to move your if condition inside your click handler. Otherwise it only runs once when the page is loaded, not every time you click the clickme div. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7gyL2h2e/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the if condition inside the click event.

Check it here http://jsfiddle.net/7gyL2h2e/6/

HTML:

```
<div id="number">8</div>
<div id="clickme">Click me +1</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#clickme").click(function(){
  $('#number').html(function(i, val) { return +val+1;});
  if($.trim($("#number").text())=="9"){
    alert("number 9");  
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function in click event to check

```
$("#clickme").click(function(){
  $('#number').html(function(i, val) { return +val+1;});
   checkme();
```

});

```
function checkme()
{
   if($.trim($("#number").text())=="9"){
  alert("number 9");  
 }
 }
```

Check the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7gyL2h2e/8/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect the number Then

```
$("#clickme").click(function(){
$('#number').html(function(i, val) { return +val+1;});
if($.trim($("#number").text())=="9"){
  alert("number 9");  
}
```

});